# How to remove auto-focus in Swing

Tags: java, swing

Whenever I run my application, Java automatically sets focus on the first component on the frame.

Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

As you can see, Java has set focus on the first button (Add a new word).

I've tried this solution but the problem is not solved :(

```
Mainframe mainframe = new Mainframe();
mainframe.requestFocusInWindow();
mainframe.setVisible(true);
```

Now, How can I disable auto-focus in my application?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html), this won't answer you question directly, but will give you a better understanding of how the whole thing works!

Comment: You can create you own FocusTraversalPolicy, by extending it.  Then calling  frame.setFocusTraversalPolicy( new YourFocusPolicy);.  You can find an example of this at http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596004088/code/#ch28  in the AlphaButtonPolicy example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work around this by setting your initial focus to the JFrame's Content Pane. Just add following code to the JFrame **after you add all other elements** to your JFrame.

`getContentPane().requestFocusInWindow();`

Comment: As per the JavaDocs [`requestFocusInWindow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocus--) is a preferred method for requesting focus for a component

Comment: Don't forget to make the frame visible before this. Otherwise the first control will be focused no matter what you do.